# Prism ToolbarTray region adapter - ServiceLocatorImplBase not found error

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, regions

(**Edited**: I am using Unity now instead of MEF but still the same issue)

I have implemented a custom region adapter for a ToolBarTray region. I am using Prism framework with Unity. Here the code:

```
[Export]
public class ToolBarTrayRegionAdapter : RegionAdapterBase<ToolBarTray>
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ToolBarTrayRegionAdapter(IRegionBehaviorFactory behaviorFactory)
        : base(behaviorFactory)
    {
    }

    protected override IRegion CreateRegion()
    {
        return new SingleActiveRegion();
    }

    protected override void Adapt(IRegion region, ToolBarTray regionTarget)
    {
        if (regionTarget.ToolBars.Count != 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Region target has toolbars");

        region.ActiveViews.CollectionChanged += delegate
        {
            regionTarget.ToolBars.Add(region.ActiveViews.FirstOrDefault() as ToolBar);
        };
    }
}
```

I have added my own custom region adapter mapping in the bootstrapper overriden method:

```
    protected override RegionAdapterMappings ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings()
    {
        RegionAdapterMappings mappings = base.ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings();
        mappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(ToolBar), Container.Resolve<ToolBarRegionAdapter>());
        mappings.RegisterMapping(typeof(ToolBarTray), Container.Resolve<ToolBarTrayRegionAdapter>());
        return mappings;
    }
```

My configuration page has a left toolbar with Navigation items for diferent modules, and each module registers a ModuleView in the ConfigurationContentRegion and a ToolBarView in the ConfigurationModulesToolBarTrayRegion. Here the xaml code for the configuration page:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutConfiguration">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Left" IsLocked="True" Orientation="Vertical" Style="{StaticResource SecondaryToolBarTrayStyle}">
            <ToolBar x:Name="NavigationItemsControl" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ConfigurationNavigationRegion" Style="{StaticResource SecondaryToolBarStyle}"/>
        </ToolBarTray>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ToolBarTray prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ConfigurationModulesToolBarTrayRegion" DockPanel.Dock="Top" IsLocked="True" Orientation="Horizontal">

            </ToolBarTray>
            <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ConfigurationContentRegion" 
                    Grid.Row="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

What I want to accomplish is: whenever the navigation item is pressed, the corresponding moduleview is loaded in the ConfigurationContentRegion and the toolbarview is loaded in the ConfigurationModulesToolBarTrayRegion.

It compiles fine, but when I press the navigation item a NullReferenceException is thrown and I get a "ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs not found" message. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong here?

This is my module toolbar view code-behind code:

```
[Export("CategoriesToolbarView")]
public partial class CategoriesToolbarView : UserControl
{
    public CategoriesToolbarView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

When the navigation item is clicked, this event loads the views into the region:

```
private void NavigateToCategoriesRadioButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ConfigurationContentRegion, categoriesViewUri);
        this.regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ConfigurationModulesToolBarTrayRegion, categoriesToolbarViewUri);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using the ServiceLocator when you have direct access to the Container? This is how you should be doing it http://brianlagunas.com/create-a-custom-prism-regionadapter/

Comment: @BrianLagunas I tried at frist configuring the region adapter mappings in the bootstrapper with the Container instead as it is described in your link. But I got this error: CompositionContainer does not contain a definition for 'Resolve' and no extension method 'Resolve' accepting a first argument of type CompositionContainer could be found.

Comment: Also note, that my bootstrapper inherits from MefBootstrapper

Comment: I don't use MEF because it is not a DI container. Most likely your issues are a result of MEF.

Comment: Do you recommend me to switch all my application to Unity? I chose MEF because the example on Microsoft Practicies about Modularity was done with MefBootstrapper

Comment: Yes. I always recommend using a true DI container such as Unity over MEF.  Plus, MEF makes a mess of you app code with all those attributes. It also makes it much more difficult to share code across different platforms.

Comment: Hi @BrianLagunas I have switched to Unity but still getting the same error... When it breakes, I see a new tab in Visual studio saying "ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs not found. You need to find ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs to view the source for the current call stack frame. Try one of the following options: browse and find ServiceLocatorImplBase.cs"

Comment: Make sure you have all the required NuGet packages/references added to your projects including CommonServiceLocator.

Comment: @BrianLagunas It is added in all projects (version 1.3)